# How to replace undefined with empty string in a textfield with Lit-element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, material-components, lit-element

I am using Lit-element and mwc-element in this project. I have two string variables and an object variable. The object holds the string values. I want to fill up the text-field based using object values.  I have successfully done this when I include values into HTML. If I don't pass in any value, the textfield is filled with "undefined" as shown in the picture below. How can I avoid this and make the textfield empty instead?

```
<person-identifier></person-identifier>

<person-identifier value='[{"use": "official","system": "urn:lumiradx:consult","value": "LDX12345"}]'></person-identifier>

import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import '@material/mwc-textfield/mwc-textfield.js';

class PersonIdentifier extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            systemIdentifier: { type: String },
            identifierField: { type: String },
            value: { type: Array }
        }
    }


    constructor() {
        super();
        this.systemIdentifier = 'true';
        this.identifierField = 'true';
        this.value = [{}];
    }


    render() {

        if (typeof (this.value) == "string") {
            this.value = JSON.parse(this.value);
        }
        return html` ${this.value.map((i, index) => html`
        ${this.systemIdentifier !== 'false' ? html`<mwc-textfield outlined value="${i.system}" @input="${e => this.value[index].system = e.target._input.value}" class="systemIdentifier" label="System:"></mwc-textfield>` : ''}
        ${this.identifierField !== 'false' ? html`<mwc-textfield outlined value="${i.value}" @input="${e => this.value[index].value = e.target._input.value}" class="identifierField" label="Identifier:"></mwc-textfield>` : ''}
        `)}`;

    }
}

customElements.define('person-identifier', PersonIdentifier);
```

[image: result]

Comment: undefined is a falsy value, so set an empty string if ``i.value`` is false, ``${i.value || ''}``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In lit-element, Use `.` notation while bining the property. So here this will be solved by just updating the binding like this `.value="${i.system}"`